# Error at Query.run when using postman and sequelize

Tags: node.js, axios, sequelize.js, postman

I am receiving this console error when trying to run my postman POST to see if it transfers over into my database.

```
Server started at http://localhost:5000
Error
    at Query.run (C:\Users\donal\videos\Web-Developement\videojs\vc-be\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\query.js:50:25) 
    at C:\Users\donal\videos\Web-Developement\videojs\vc-be\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:313:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async PostgresQueryInterface.insert (C:\Users\donal\videos\Web-Developement\videojs\vc-be\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:297:21)
    at async model.save (C:\Users\donal\videos\Web-Developement\videojs\vc-be\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2424:35)
    at async Function.create (C:\Users\donal\videos\Web-Developement\videojs\vc-be\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1336:12)     
    at async C:\Users\donal\videos\Web-Developement\videojs\vc-be\server\controllers\auth.js:12:18
```

Here is my code below:

```
const { Op } = require("sequelize");
const { User } = require('../sequelize');
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const asyncHandler = require('../middlewares/asyncHandler');

// exports.signup = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
//  console.log('this function works');
// });

exports.signup =  asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = await User.create(req.body);

    await user.save();

    res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: token });

    console.log('this function works');
    
});
```

and my schema for my database:

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    return sequelize.define("User", {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      },
      firstname: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      lastname: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
          isEmail: true,
        },
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          min: 6,
        },
      },
      avatar: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        defaultValue:
          "https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/b0b4c759-ad9c-4425-a9f4-ab89e2fd9837/de8cefl-35c0bc59-59b9-42ab-b19f-5c73828bb78e.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcL2IwYjRjNzU5LWFkOWMtNDQyNS1hOWY0LWFiODllMmZkOTgzN1wvZGU4Y2VmbC0zNWMwYmM1OS01OWI5LTQyYWItYjE5Zi01YzczODI4YmI3OGUucG5nIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.81ixeN9b4cfDmfBlskK9CUyAMDtRhYNU7lfwTI8WI5Q",
      },
      cover: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        defaultValue:
          "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1410507368622919685/AU_Zqm1J_400x400.jpg",
      },
      channelDescription: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      isAdmin: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: false,
      },
    });
  };
```

I am new to sequelize and axios. Still trying to figure out why I am getting this error. If anyone can give me some pointers, I'd appreciate it.

I have also included the request.body, to see if there is something wrong with it.
[Request.Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDKrV.png)

UPDATE: I have changed the syntax to isolate the error, it still shows query.run, it now returns the error 500 whenever I use this specific syntax:

```
exports.signup = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { username, email, password, firstname, lastname } = req.body;


        //create user document and save in database
        const user = await User.create({
            username,
            email,
            password,
            firstname,
            lastname,
        });

        await user.save();

       

        res.status(201).send(
            'successfully sent!'
        )
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).send('Error occured. Please try again');
    }

};
```

UPDATE: I have added a picture of the databases, making sure to see if there's any errors there.

Comment: can you pls add request.body in the questions too, since its important to know what data are you trying to create

Comment: I have added the request.body in the image tag below. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't see the error message itself? Can you show it?

Comment: It's the first syntax example ontop where it says "Error at query.run"

Comment: I am not sure but, Can you try adding isAdmin field in your request body ?

Comment: I've added "isAdmin": true to my POST request, that still gave me an error back. The sequelize is able to connect to the postgres server. I have not figured out why it won't send the data through.

Comment: Usually, after the block of your Error Query.run, you should see the detail of the error but if you don't see it it is suppressed for some reason. without looking at the detail, it is hard to say the actual issue. My wild guess is one of the `unique` constraints is failing (email, username).  but anyhow, you should figure out why the actual error is not printed.

Comment: I've updated the syntax, I think it has something to do with the req.body, but I will take a look at the unique constraints as well. The error in postman is the 500 error with the error occured.

Comment: Do one thing just check your table's SQL from PGadmin, Is it perfectly created as you have defined the model ? If yes then just console log the error in catch block and add it in your question.